# Lipschitz function, Berkeley problem 1.2.2

Tags: lipschitz-functions

> > Problem 1.2.2
> > Suppose that $f$ maps compact interval $I$ into itself and that
> > $$\mid f(x)-f(y) \mid < \mid x-y \mid$$
> > for all $x, y \in  I, x\neq y$. Can one conclude that there is some constant $M<1$ such that, for all $x, y \in I$, $$\mid f(x)-f(y) \mid \leq M\mid x-y \mid$$?

If such function exists it is not continuously differentiable, otherwise $f'$ will attain supremum.

I tried to define $g: I \times I \rightarrow I$ s.t. $g(x,y)=\frac{\mid f(x)-f(y) \mid}{\mid x-y \mid}$ which is continuous and attains supremum. But $g$ is not defined for $x=y$

Please give hint. Please do not give solution. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: the answer is negative.

Comment: @uniquesolution Thanks. I found a counterexample

Comment: What is the problem of attaining supremum ?

Comment: You want a function which has derivative $1$ at one end of the interval, and less than $1$ on the rest of the interval.

Comment: @EDX case i: $sup \{ g(x, y) \mid x\neq y \}<1$. Then $M=sup \{ g(x, y) \mid x\neq y \}$. Case ii: $sup \{ g(x, y) \mid x\neq y \}=1$. If $g$ were defined and continuous, its image is closed and $g$ attains its supremum which is a contradiction. So case ii is false.

Comment: Watch out because the condition doesn't tell you $M=\sup{g(x,y) | x \neq y}$ . Taking $g=0$, we can choose $M=\frac{1}{2}$ and we don't get $M=sup{g(x,y) | x \neq y}$

Comment: @EDX your example falls in case i and $sup\{ g(x,y) \mid x\neq y \} (=0)$ also works as an $M$. So my argument holds.

Comment: The case is that $M$ is not unique in the definition given. So you've to precise that $M$ is unique or to precise it is defined as $M=sup(g)$